# Pandas sorts col values unnecessarily when concatenating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes I want to concatinate, basically one is a utility bill and that information, and the other dataframe is units in an apartment complex and their usage (their usage adds up to the utility bill)

I want to display these side by side, but when I try to it sort of UN-sorts my units col. How can I concatinate these two dataframes without it re-sorting my units col incorrectly?

(the NaN values are totally fine, everything is perfect except the order the units are in)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = ({
           "usage": [651, 123, 123, 543, 651],
           "units": [1, 10, 11, 2, 3]
      })

df2 = ({
           "utility": ["ELE"],
           "usage": [2091]
      })

df1 = pd.DataFrame (df1, columns = ['usage','units'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame (df2, columns = ['utility','usage'])

print(df1)
output =  usage  units  
     0    651      1
     1    123     10
     2    123     11
     3    543      2
     4    651      3

df1.units = df1.units.astype(int)
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='units', ascending=True)

print(df1)
output =  usage  units
     0    651      1
     3    543      2
     4    651      3
     1    123     10
     2    123     11

df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)

print(df3)
output = utility   usage  usage  units
   0     ELE  2091.0    651      1
   1     NaN     NaN    123     10
   2     NaN     NaN    123     11
   3     NaN     NaN    543      2
   4     NaN     NaN    651      3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call a reset_index after the sorting. as such

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='units', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Holy shit, thank you so much! I had tried to reset the index but only after I concatinated. I didn't realize I had to do it after sorting but that makes so much sense. You are my hero

Comment: The question was well formulated & exemplified